# WordPress Plugin is upload very slow

Tags: php, wordpress

I have developed a plugin which has features of importing products from different online stores.

Now the total size of plugin is 4.4 MB which is creating issue for clients because its taking a huge time to upload. what is the good way of compressing the plugin to make it small? or any method of making it to upload fast.

Comment: I have used Ultra compression on 7-Zip and WinRaR but it did not made the difference

Comment: please support your post with code.

Comment: Hi there are multiple files and thousand of lines of code. how do I share all of them?

Comment: Please edit your question and be more specific.